# Is post-incrementing the iterator during a container erase always a bug?

Tags: c++, c++11

Debugging some code, I found an invalid use of an iterator.  So I searched our code-base for further bad usages.  I found a few of these:

```
it = cppContainer.erase( it++ );
```

(Where `it` is a valid container iterator before this line, and `cppContainer` is a STL container, e.g. vector).

This sparked a discussion on whether the `it++` was merely redundant, or whether it was post-incrementing the iterator after the call to the container `.erase()` made it invalid, which would be *bad*.

Is this form always a bug?   Obviously the `++` is unnecessary, but is it wrong?

The general consensus among the engineers was that it was *potentially* bad.

Comment: Why do you want to risk it? `erase` may yield `end`, so you should check for it before incrementing. If you increment blindly, then `it` will be beyond `end` and then you are in UB wonderland.

Comment: The better question might be is there any case where it is not a bug and performs a useful function?

Comment: @mariusm - Yeah I don't want the risk, I have since repaired all of them.  Just wondering if there *was* a risk.

Comment: @Kingsley it depends on what you do with it afterwards. This statement alone will not give trouble, but the problem is that this kind of statement is usually in some loop dereferencing `it` and it will result in UB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> or whether it was post-incrementing the iterator after the call to the container `.erase()` made it invalid.

Please note that the arguments are fully evaluated *before* the function is called. You can conceptually imagine the post-increment as below:

```
auto operator++(int) {
  auto cp = *this;
  ++*this;
  return cp;
}
```

As you can see, the increment is done *before* the `erase` function is called; ergo, this is not undefined, but possibly inefficient.

The only way this would be undefined is if `it++` is already undefined on its own. For instance, `it` is the end iterator, or it is already invalidated, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the points I see that can/should be addressed:

- `it++` This increments the iterator and returns the old value, and is done before the `erase`. This is ok - unless `it == end` (or `it` is otherwise invalid) then it is UB.
- But the incrementing is at best pointless because `erase` on a `std::vector`

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase [*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/vector#modifiers-3)

- However, then right after `it` is overwritten so that nobody can use the now invalid iterator.

So, the increment is pointless and arguably dangerous since it could lead somebody to think that the *assignment* is needless, and that `cppContainer.erase( it++ );` is how you should do it. This is made more confusing since: `cppContainer.erase( it++ );` leads to `it` being invalid if `cppContainer` is a `std::vector`, while `it` is still good if it is a `std::list`.

> Invalidates only the iterators and references to the erased elements.[*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/list#modifiers-3)

Ps. Just to be clear: `it = cppContainer.erase( it );` is the canonical and correct way to do it across all standard library containers.